# I am little Confused for thein selection of Sharing Mode for the Unique data from the CSV config file

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

Could some one please clarify on the below.

"I am little Confused for in selection of Sharing Mode to read Unique data from the CSV config file"

Below is the my Test Design.
Stepping Thread Group:

- Total No.Of Users  : 3
- Total No.Of Scenarios/ThroughPut Controller Thread Group  : 3
- Each Scenario /ThroughPut Controller Thread Group has his own CSV file
- CSV file Sharing Mode : CurrentThread Group
  Please see the below screenshots.

My goal is to select the unique data from the CSV  file associated to each Thread Group per user as well as per iteration.

So should i user Sharing Mode  : All Threads or CurrentThread Group to read unique data ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So should i user Sharing Mode : All Threads or CurrentThread Group to read unique data ?

Based on screenshots, you have only 1 thread group called `jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group`, so it doesn't matter if you choose `All threads` or `Current thread group`, they will work the same for 1 thread group. You should not choose `Current thread` or `Identifier` though.

The elements `NGP_NewEmployee` etc (your scenarios) are 3 controllers *within* the same thread group, they are not additional thread groups.

If your goal is

> to select the unique data from the CSV file associated to each Thread Group per user as well as per iteration.

then you don't need 3 instances of `CSV Data Set Config` object under each controller. Instead have 1 instance of this object, right under thread group, on the same level as your `NGP_<...>` controllers (or even above thread group on global level).

If you plan to add more thread groups in the future, and you want all thread groups to use unique data, then move `CSV Data Set Config` object under root (Test Plan) element, and change its mode to `All Threads`.

Comment: Let me re phrase it !  3 CSV config has different data associated to each Scenario/Throughput Controller, so has to keep 3 CSV files.The idea is  total No.of users defined in jp@gc  are distributed b/w 3 scenarios,so within the scenario 1 user with N no. of iterations has  to read  unique data from the associated CSV config file.From the above screenshots take NewEmployee scenario 1 User with N iterations has to read unique data from the CSV config tied to this,so NewEmployee CSV config Sharing mode should be  AllThreads or Current ThreadGroup?

Comment: As I said before: since you have only 1 thread group, the behavior of `All threads` and `Current thread group` will be the same way for you. But do you want all threads to be unique comparing to each other, or each thread needs to use the same set of values as other threads, but should loop through them between iterations? If the second, use "Current thread" rather